# (load-theme) at the bottom of .emacs, or manually renders a different screen

Tags: init-file, themes, commands, rendering

Adding this line at the very end of the `.emacs` file, that loads a default theme coming with the Emacs package,

```
(load-theme 'tsdh-dark)
```

the (main) screen looks like

[image]

Note the black-on-dark text, the barely visible mini-buffer, and other syntax highlighted languages (C++, Perl...) have all a lot of dark-on-dark text.

Now, if, instead, I do the command manually, right after `.emacs` was executed (ie first command),

> <kbd>M-x</kbd> load-theme → tsdh-dark

the highlighting is normal,

[image]

in all languages.

Why is it that running as the *last* lisp instruction in `.emacs` the rendering is wrong, while loading the theme manually just after works?

And how can I fix that?

(I realized that the command might do more than just the `(load-theme)` lisp instruction... this question is also to fix the problem in a clean way)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you use Emacs in the client/server configuration? My guess is that for some reason Emacs is redefining faces after loading the theme. I can't find any reference but I think Emacs finishes setting up some of the faces when it makes the frame, at least for client frames, which is after it has loaded the init file (but, of course, before you can call `load-theme` interactively). The way I had found to delay face settings until everything was well defined was to call a function that applies the settings from `after-make-frame-functions`:

```lisp
(load-theme 'tsdh-dark t)

(defun load-tsdh-dark-theme (_frame)
  (enable-theme 'tsdh-dark))

(add-hook 'after-make-frame-functions #'load-tsdh-dark-theme)
```

---

Even simpler, try loading the theme with `(load-theme 'tsdh-dark t)` (notice the additional `t`). From `C-h f load-theme RET`:

> This function is normally called through Customize when setting
> ‘custom-enabled-themes’.  If used directly in your init file, it
> should be called with a non-nil NO-CONFIRM argument, or after
> ‘custom-safe-themes’ has been loaded.

I can't reproduce your issue on Emacs 27, so I'm guessing...

Comment: Hi, no it's not a client/server config. Currently Emacs 25 (Ubuntu 18.04). Will upgrade soon, maybe the problem will disappear. Unfortunately adding the code above to the *.emacs* file doesn't improve the rendering. Maybe there is a way to postpone (timer) the execution of `load-theme`?

Comment: I don't think a timer is the right solution here. Did you try the hook with non-nil `NO-CONFIRM` in the `load-theme` form (as in the updated code block)?

Comment: Just did, no change :(

Comment: I don't really know how to fix it then, but I've got a couple more ideas that you might try if no one more knowledgeable answers. First, try `(customize-set-variable 'custom-enabled-themes '(tsdh-dark))` after `(load-theme 'tsdh-dark t)`. If that doesn't work, I've simplified the hook, give it a try.

Comment: @e2-e4 That's the dirtiest theme setting I've ever seen :-) Did you try with `customize-set-variable`? I'm curious about it..

Comment: I thought you died in 1862 ... :)

Comment: @e2-e4 Oh, that was my great-great-great-grandfather! He too was an Emacs user. Started using it when it was still written in TECO…

Comment: Ok :) Did you get the gold? That's all that matters....

Comment: @e2-e4 He did get it but he squandered most of it on bribing the damn comrades into keeping it shut about him using a program written by yankees.

Comment: @e2-e4 Did it work? If yes, what did work? Tell me please so I can give it prominence in the answer.

Comment: Well, it seems it could be a problem from my complex .emacs (lots of personal stuff, frames...), and it would be a waste not to allocate the 50 rep. So, let just say... I'm (the) Good... :)

Comment: @e2-e4 Well, thank you. I tested all the things I have suggested on Emacs 27, so do upgrade and good luck. \*\*Takes the bounty and rides away\*\*

Answer (score 1):

Try:
`(custom-set-variables '(custom-enabled-themes (quote (tsdh-dark))))`

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it seems by delaying the execution (200ms), I can get it to work correctly.

Adding this to the bottom of *~/.emacs*

```
(run-at-time "0.2" nil (lambda nil (load-theme (quote tsdh-dark) nil nil)))
```